# commands in shell script not working, but individual ones working in terminal

Tags: for-loop, awk, scripting, sh

my script is simple it's only

```
#!/bin/sh
temp = $1
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
        awk -v j=$i '$1=j{print $1,$2,$3}' $temp #> text${i}.txt
done
```

and when I invoke

```
./shellScript.sh file.txt
```

Nothing happens, it runs forever and if i try to look at the files they're empty

Yet when I command line

```
awk -v j=1 '$1=j{print $1,$2,$3}' file.txt
```

Everything prints as it

Comment: `temp = $1` is not valid shell syntax. Pay attention to the syntax error message you are getting and use `temp="$1"` (no spaces and quote the parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's an invalid syntax, `temp = $1` is not valid. In fact it's valid, if `temp` is a program in your `$PATH`, `=` and `$1` will be given as parameter. That's why your shell is whining about `temp` being not found.

As `temp` is not affected, it's empty, so you're giving no file to `awk`. When getting no files, `awk` reads from `stdin`, that's why your script does not stop by itself.

A tip, you should think about protecting your variables by writing them between double quotes, it's not everytime what you need, but protecting they by default is easier to debug and almost all the time what's you really need, typically, this one is working:

```
temp="My Document.txt"
awk -v j="$i" '$1=j {print $1,$2,$3}' "$temp"
```

But not this one, giving `My` and `Document.txt` to `awk` as two serparate arguments.

```
temp="My Document.txt"
awk -v j="$i" '$1=j {print $1,$2,$3}' $temp
```

Also, to generate `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` there's a tool, named `seq`, typically `seq 10` gives you this sequence.

Here is a working version:

```
#!/bin/sh
temp="$1"
for i in $(seq 10)
do
    awk -v j="$i" '$1=j {print $1,$2,$3}' "$temp" > "text${i}.txt"
done
```

It works on your "command line" because you're giving "file.txt", in your script, "$temp" was empty due to the affectation failure.

There's a nice way to debug shell scripts, it's `sh -x`, if I reproduce your affectation bug, here is what I get:

```
$ sh -x test.sh foo.txt
+ temp = foo.txt
test.sh: 2: test.sh: temp: not found
+ seq 10
+ awk -v j=1 $1=j {print $1,$2,$3}
```

Here, you clearly see that `sh` executes `awk -v j=1 $1=j {print $1,$2,$3}` without a file parameter: bug found.